# Can I run a python script from a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: python, autohotkey

I want to be able to run a python script like a keyboard macro, just by pressing a certain combination of buttons. Is it possible, if yes, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your operating system there will be different ways to run scripts via hot keys. If you create and run a script with "key listeners" you can use that to execute other scripts. There are a few libraries you could use and I've attached a couple of them below.

[PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

[Pynput](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you're on a Mac, you can create a 'quick action' in Automate using an apple script to tell Terminal to do something like 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "python myscript.py"'. Then, you can go into your keyboard shortcut preferences and add a hotkey to the action.

Answer (score -1):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>. It worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

you click f5 if you have windows

Comment: Can you elaborate how? F5 just seems to refresh the page.